# SSRS group on only one value on a chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have data that I need to present in both a bar and line chart as one this how the chart is laid out in SSRS:

- Series Group: Location

---

- Category Group: Year
- Category Group: Month

---

- Values (Y Axis): Site_count (Bar chart)
- Values (Y Axis):Network_count (Line chart)

My issue is that the Correspondences_count for both of these are being grouped by location. I need to prevent the line chart one being added to the location grouping, so that way it shows a single line.

I found this, that seems to show how this might be able to be done.. . however its not working for me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74d9affc-ebf3-485c-988e-f28f7049b600/how-to-make-one-of-the-chart-ignore-series-grouping

Any help is as always appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The process described in that link should be OK.

Say I have some sample data:

[image]

And a simple chart that has the same issue you're describing:

[image]

[image]

Under the `Network_count` Chart Series properties, change the **Value field** expression to:

```
=Sum(Fields!Network_count.Value, "Month_CategoryGroup")
```

[image]

Here, `Month_CategoryGroup` is the name of a Category Group:

[image]

Now the `Network_count` value is the total for all `Locations`:

[image]

You'll note I've removed `Network_count` from the Legend:

[image]

This was displaying incorrectly so I just removed it. If you still want a Legend, the easiest thing would be to create something with a tablix/textboxes outside of the chart.

Comment: Did this answer help at all?